# Vue.set() on nested array properties

Tags: arrays, vue.js, nested, set

i've been trying to trigger Vue DOM updates by updating an array the old way and it obviously wont do it because of the ceveats on Vue detecting object/array changes. I dont know how to access my nested array properties by using Vue.set. Normally i would access and assign my property like this (by the way this is a state in Vuex):

```
state.timelines[0].events[0].item.info = payload.info
```

I dont know how to access and assign that property with .set, i've tried a few combinations but they failed to work. Thanks.

Comment: How is your `timelines` state before you trying to update it like that? I mean, is it an empty array? If not, is events an `empty` array? And so on.

Comment: I got it right!, i thought i was manipulating an array, but in fact i was trying to alter the "item" object, so i used 
`Vue.set(state.timelines[i].events[0].item, 'info', payload.info)` and its now working properly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, nice. It really depended on your case, but since you worked it out, then that's it. Btw, should we add a generic answer or will you delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

*Solution:* when trying to alter an object property, even if its deep in nested arrays, just use: `Vue.set(arrayA[indexA].arrayB[indexB].object('objectPropertyName', newValue))`

If dealing with arrays use:
`Vue.set(array, arrayIndex, newValue)`.

Comment: did you missing something like closing parenthesis on your code example there ?